# git workflow for switching a few files between different versions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, reference, workflow

I've got a large Visual Studio solution (dozens of projects; thousands of files) that I don't have the option of reorganizing. I'm troubleshooting a problem and need to switch back and forth between two versions of several files in the solution. Currently the diff between those files are in `branch_a` and `branch_b`. As I troubleshoot I may need to commit on either branch, but the changes in either branch won't be in the files I'm concerned about switching back and forth between.

Is there a well-known or straightforward workflow or set of git commands that would allow me to flip back and forth between the two versions of just those couple of files?

If it matters, what I'm switching back and forth between are two versions of a dll of a third party library that are referenced in 3 of the dozens of projects - I'm hoping to avoid going into each project, removing `library_a.dll` and adding `library_b.dll` and then the reverse on those projects, so the files that are actually being switched are the `.proj` files with the differing references.

Obviously (or perhaps not so) non-git solutions to the same problem are also welcome, but since git is tracking the files that seemed like an obvious choice.

Comment: is there something undesirable about doing it directly? `git checkout thatbranch -- dll-dir/'*.dll' path/to/other.dll`

Comment: that would probably work but as an alternative it looks like if I can keep all my modifications local I can checkout the commit before and after the project file changes (I know this goes against what I was saying about needing to commit against either branch, but perhaps that's really the flaw in my workflow) and that would work ok.